# ASP.net Login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

How to show a validation summary message (javascript alert message) if username and password is empty in asp.net login congrol. By default it show * as message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property

```
LoginContol.FailureText = "Your Message"
```

Also check the properties

```
PasswordRequiredErrorMessage 

UserNameRequiredErrorMessage
```